# How to solve "No compatible browser found" error in Okta login?

Tags: android, authentication, browser, okta, okta-api

While trying to login into the OKTA login page, the android device is giving this error,
And the login fails.

```
D/MainActivity: null onError
    AuthorizationException: {"type":0,"code":10,"errorDescription":"No compatible browser found"}
        at com.okta.oidc.AuthenticationResultHandler.handleAuthenticationResult
```

Dependencies used for Okta OIDC

```
implementation 'com.okta.authn.sdk:okta-authn-sdk-api:1.0.0'
implementation('com.okta.authn.sdk:okta-authn-sdk-impl:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.okta.sdk', module: 'okta-sdk-httpclient'
}
implementation 'com.okta.android:oidc-androidx:1.0.11'
```

The browser used is the default browser for the device. (Vivo browser)
All permissions are given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set **Chrome** as your default browser.

Steps to follow:

1. Go to settings on your device.
2. Go to Permission management.
3. Go to Default app settings.
4. Go to Browser.
5. Select application: Chrome.
   Now, your default browser is set to Chrome.
6. Rerun the app and try login again.

[image]

Comment: If you use the SyncWebAuthClient, the sdk always throws this error on an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer won't work if you're developing an app targeting Android 11 (API 30) or higher.

Because of [Package Visibility Filtering](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)

In order to see packages that support custom tabs (which is what the Okta SDK is looking for), you have to declare a query in your manifest.  This one works for me:

```
 <queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```